# Calculate the expected value of $T_{1}$? What about expected value of $T_{2}$?

Tags: expected-value

Let $N_{t}$ be an inhomogeneous Poisson process with current intensity $3\cdot \ln(1+t)$. Calculate the distribution for $T_{1} (=S_{1})$ and conditional distribution $T_{2} (=S_{2}-S_{1})$ conditional on $T_{1}$ and unconditional distribution for $T_{2}$. How much is expected value of $T_{1}$? What about expected value of $T_{2}$?

So far I got this:[image]

[image]
[image]

So I need to calculate the distribution for $T_{2}$ and both expected values but I get weird integrals.

Any help?

Comment: Try to type at least the main ideas in MathJax (don’t need every line of working). Here is a [quick tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

Let $\lambda(t)$ be the intensity function and $\Lambda(t) = \int_0^t \lambda(s)\ \mathsf ds$. For any $t>0$ we have $\{T_1>t\}=\{N(t)=0\}$ and hence
$$
\mathbb P(T_1>t) = \mathbb P(N(t)=0) = e^{-\Lambda(t)}.
$$
Differentiating the above, we find the density of $T_1$:
$$
f_{T_1}(t) = -\frac{\mathsf d}{\mathsf dt}\mathbb P(T_1>t) = \lambda(t)e^{-\Lambda(t)},\ t>0.
$$
Similarly,  the probability of $\{T_2-T_1\geqslant t\}$ conditioned on $\{T_1=s\}$, is $e^{\Lambda(s)-\Lambda(s+t)}$, and differentiating yields the conditional density:
$$
f_{T_2\mid T_1=s}(t\mid s) = \lambda(s+t)e^{\Lambda(s)-\Lambda(s+t)},\ t>0.
$$
The joint density of $(T_1,T_2)$ is then given by the product:
$$
f_{T_1,T_2}(s,t) = f_{T_1}(s)f_{T_2\mid T_1=s}(t\mid s) = \lambda(s)\lambda(s+t)e^{-\Lambda(s+t)},\ s,t>0.
$$
The marginal density of $T_2$ is obtained by integrating the joint density with respect to $T_1$:
$$
f_{T_2}(t) = \int_{\mathbb R} f_{T_1,T_2}(s,t)\ \mathsf ds.
$$

Comment: So is my calculation correct or not?

Comment: I cannot read the handwriting.

Comment: I think my handwriting is really good for man.

Comment: @NikiSedlarević I wasn's peaking of the penmanship; the individual symbols are discernible. But that is all I see - pages full of one line of symbols after another, with no indication to the reader as to the overall meaning. "Is my calculation correct?" - well...which one? A few sentences explaining what you've done and where you're stuck would make this more clear.